# Setting default zoom level in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2

With your help I was able get a shapefile from the CAD file of the previous question.

Now the next step is the display the shapefile in OpenLayers... I wrote the script but the map being displayed in the browser is way too small... I need help setting the default zoom level...

Can someone point me to an "simple" example that explains how to set the default zoom level?

The ones I've found a way to complicated...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second argument to map.setCenter is a zoom.

```
  var map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
  // add layers here
  map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(yourlon, yourlat), 5);
```

If you want something more complex than that, you're probably going to need to share more details about what your map and setup currently look like. (Projection, base layer, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the replies!!! But still no luck.... 
 
Here's the link to my "map".... Hopefully someone take a look at the source page and let me know what I'm doing wrong...

[link] (http://tobagoborn.com/gis/science/floor13.html)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone for taking the time to reply...   
After reading everything I started from scratch.  The key was figuring out the center lat/lon.  I did this by running get.center() on the command prompt on firebug...   

Chris

Answer (score 3):

Exemples are *complexes* because the way it works is not that simple

Since **Zoom level** and **resolution** are linked together, it could be a good start for you to read about it on the wiki page : http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/SettingZoomLevels,
then choose the best way to process for the project you're working on.

Answer (score 3):

*Another way to set extent like you want*

-Zoom to the extent you desired

-Get your current bbox

```
currentBbox = map.getExtent().left + ","+ map.getExtent().bottom + "," + map.getExtent().right + "," + map.getExtent().top;
```

-Copy result you got from console below

```
console.log(currentBbox)
```

-Reuse the result you got by pasting it in map.zoomToExtent(new OpenLayers.Bounds(stringYouCopy));

So in your case, do in firebug console

```
map.zoomToExtent(new OpenLayers.Bounds(-1.395751953125, -2.051635742188, 11.787841796875, 10.582641601562));
```

If it's ok, you can add the code to your Openlayers application

*Reusing "Christopher Schmidt" advice with map.setCenter, to get the right informations*

-Zoom to the place you want

-To get lon

```
map.center.lon
```

-To get lat

```
map.center.lat
```

-To get zoom

```
map.zoom
```

It's up to you to complete (easy now)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to zoom to the extent of your map using `map.zoomToExtent(layer.getExtent())`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy, bigger the value, bigger the zoom:

```
map.getView().setZoom(8);
```